# Do web.config role and usernames allow whitespace?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is the following valid?  Are roles/usernames allowed to have whitespace?

```
<location path="MyPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow role="Good User" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: However **role** should be roles   <allow roles="..." />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are :-)

Actually, it depends on the MembershipProvider/RoleProvider. But all the standard ones (SQL, Windows, AD) permit spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use **allow roles** multiple times if your groups have spaces:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="User Group 1"/>
        <allow roles="User Group 2"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```